# Configuring K2-Blackpearl Services to Enable Mobile Connectivity

Tags: rest, wcf, k2-blackpearl, k2-smartforms, k2-smartobjects

I am trying to connect to K2 blackpearl sever using k2 mobile application (Android application called "K2 Mobile").

When I was searching I got this information on mobile configuration as below.

> To support the mobile applications you must expose the SyncREST.svc endpoints included in K2 Services on your extranet

Can anyone help me on how to expose the  `SyncREST.svc` endpoints included in the K2 services on my extranet

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a endpoint configuration, go to your K2 Blackpearl installation folder and refer to the url below.

https://www.k2.com/onlinehelp/k2blackpearl/devref/4.6.7/webframe.html#Service_Settings.html

This should set you up to access it within your network.

Next you will need to enable the firewall and ports, so that the mobile app can access the endpoints.